# [pg_dump]Extract only tables and views from a schema

Tags: sql, postgresql, ddl, pg-dump

I am trying to extract the ddl of all the tables and views which are present in a schema of a postgres db.

I am able to export, but in the export it is also including create function and other objects.

Is there any way using which we can only extract tables and views from a schema? Either via limiting the access to objects or by editting a file?

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

some options maybe redundant.

```
pg_dump --dbname=test15 --schema=public --schema-only -N '*catalog*' -t 'public.*'  > test.sql
```

main gottcha:

```
-t pattern
--table=pattern
    Dump only tables with names matching pattern.
```

The manual have many examples. You can follow it through.

Comment: Hi , Thanks for providing the inputs. But currently I am using similar command only but it is fetching all the objects with start with the prefix which includes all the functions indexes and sequences . What I want specifically is only tables and views which are present in a particular schema . It there a way using parameters we can address this ? --table approach is nice but it also exports sequences as well . Is there a restricted access possible using which we can only access tables and view only and no other objects?

Comment: @logicNotFound I tried with `-T '*seq*'`. It will not work. The reason is probably the Data definition is sequence is part of data definition.

Comment: I tried following other threads , i also tried creating a custome dump file using pg_dump and using pg_restore -l i was able to see it's table of contents. Is there a way to edit this file so we can remove the erroneous enteries and get the required ddl ?

Comment: if you pg_dump to .sql file then you can edit the .sql file. Then use psql to execute  .sql file. I am not sure about about file format.@logicNotFound